# JavaScript if/else issue: 'Yes" is treated as 'No' due to being case sensitive

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am new at learning JS, and I wrote my own version of one of the exercises I was doing to try and remember what I had learned. Here is what I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>

alert("Good morning!");
var hire = prompt("Are you here because you're interested in hiring me?");

if (hire === "yes") {
    alert("You've just made my day. Carry on.")
}

else {
    alert("Well, I hope you're at least thinking about it.")
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, if you don't type 'yes' in all lowercase letters, it assumes that the answer falls under the 'else' category and spits out the wrong answer. I have been reading about ways to convert it to uppercase, but I still can't figure out what extra code it needs. Thanks.

Comment: [String.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: @Jason It is not confirm...

Comment: @adeneo - it is just an exercise, I am still getting the hang of if/else statements and using prompts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.toLowerCase()` in order to force their response to be in lower case. Then you can check against it always being in lower case.

```
if (hire.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
    alert('You\'ve just made my day. Carry on.');
} else {
    alert('Well, I hope you\'re at least thinking about it.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be fine

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script>

    alert("Good morning!");
    var hire = prompt("Are you here because you're interested in hiring me?");

    if (hire.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
        alert("You've just made my day. Carry on.")
    }

    else {
        alert("Well, I hope you're at least thinking about it.")
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: when I anwered it, your answer was not arrived.

Comment: timestamps beg to differ